# How to install YugabyteDB on Windows laptop?

Tags: windows, yugabytedb

How to install Yugabyte database on Windows 10?

The download page mentions only macOS and Linux: https://download.yugabyte.com/local

Answer (score 1):

adding to @FranckPachot's comment,  also you can download centos or any Linux OS images (VDI) files and open it through VmWare Player or HyperV from your windows laptop and create the VM and install the Yugabyte DB as mentioned from second step of his comment (i.e Sudo yum install -y python). Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

One is with Docker Desktop (https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows) and following the Docker installation.

The other is on the Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL) which runs Ubunto 20.04 LTS (installed from https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N6SVWS3RX71).
I've installed it with this:

```
franck@YB-Franck:~$ uname -a
Linux YB-Franck 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 22:23:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

franck@YB-Franck:~$ sudo yum install -y python

franck@YB-Franck:~$ wget -qs https://downloads.yugabyte.com/releases/2.11.1.0/yugabyte-2.11.1.0-b305-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

franck@YB-Franck:~$ tar xvfz yugabyte-2.11.1.0-b305-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

franck@YB-Franck:~$ cd yugabyte-2.11.1.0/

franck@YB-Franck:~$  ./bin/post_install.sh

franck@YB-Franck:~$ ./bin/yugabyted start
```

But of course, use the latest version.